# Comparar dos Strings ignorando las tildes Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

¿alguien sabe si kotlin tiene alguna funcion para comaparar dos palabras ignorando los acentos?
por ejemplo, quiero que si se da el siguiente caso, contara como que las palabras son iguales:

```
val pal1= "música"
val pal2= "musica"
if(pal1.equals(pal2))´{
Log.i(TAG,"palabras iguales")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) para comparar las strings, especificando `Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION` para ignorar los acentos. Un ejemplo:

```
import java.text.Collator

fun main() {
    val comparator = Collator.getInstance()
    comparator.strength = Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION

    val pal1= "música"
    val pal2= "musica"
    if(comparator.compare(pal1, pal2) == 0) {
        println("$pal1 y $pal2 son iguales")
    } else {
        println("$pal1 y $pal2 son diferentes")
    }
}
```

Cuya salida es:

```
música y musica son iguales
```

Te adjunto un link al [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/IUgH51n2q) para que pruebes el código que te adjunto.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Similar a como se realiza en Java usando la clase [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) y su constante [NO_DECOMPOSITION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#NO_DECOMPOSITION).

> Con [NO_DECOMPOSITION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#NO_DECOMPOSITION) establecido, los caracteres acentuados no se
> descompondrán para la intercalación. Esta es la configuración
> predeterminada y proporciona la intercalación más rápida, pero solo
> producirá resultados correctos para los idiomas que no usan acentos.

Ejemplo
**Java**:

```
   String a = "música de noção";
   String b = "musica de nocao";

   final Collator instance = Collator.getInstance();
   // Esta estrategia significa que ignorará los acentos
   instance.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);
   // Imprimirá 0 porque ambas cadenas son iguales
    Log.i(TAG,"resultado: " + instance.compare(a, b));
   //Realizando la comparación
   if(instance.compare(a, b) == 0){
      Log.i(TAG,"palabras iguales");
   }
```

Esta sería la forma de realizar la comparación en lenguaje **Kotlin**:

```
    val a = "música de noção"
    val b = "musica de nocao"
    val instance: Collator = Collator.getInstance()
    // Esta estrategia significa que ignorará los acentos
    instance.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION)
    // Imprimirá 0 porque ambas cadenas son iguales
    Log.i(TAG,"resultado: ${instance.compare(a, b)}")
    //Realizando la comparación
    if(instance.compare(a, b) == 0){
        Log.i(TAG,"palabras iguales");
    }
```